# java compiler, generics и наследование

Tags: java

Есть некий обобщенный интерфейс и класс, его реализующий.

```
interface Contract<T> {
    void doIt(T arg);
}

class Impl implements Contract<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void doIt(Integer arg) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

При создании экземпляра `Impl` и вызове метода следующим образом

```
Contract obj = new Impl();
obj.doIt(42);
```

компилятор вежливо предупреждает, что Unchecked call ... .

Я сделал следующий вывод - компилятор не смотрит на то, метод какого класса будет фактически вызван. Вот смотрит он что `Contract#doIt(T arg)` дергают и предупреждает, что надо бы тип передать. А то что тип передали в класс, который будет всю работу делать от него скрыто.

Я правильно всё понял?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Суть тут в том, что вы явно не указали, какой тип в дженерике будет, то есть компилятор не знает об этом, а это чревато ошибкой в рантайме. То есть в приведеном вами коде можно написать так:

```
Contract obj = new Impl();
obj.doIt("123"); //можно передать String и компилятор это съест
```

Но когда вы запустите этот код, вы получите `ClassCastException`. Почему? 
Потому что в случае с дженериком в параметре метода компилятор создает так называемый bridge-метод и после компиляции ваш класс `Impl` будет иметь 2 метода:

```
public void doIt(Integer arg) {
    System.out.println("hi");
}


public void doIt(Object arg) {
    doIt((Integer) arg); //тут ClassCastException
}
```

> компилятор вежливо предупреждает, что Unchecked call

Собственно, предупреждает, потому что если вы напишите вот так:

```
Contract<Integer> obj = new Impl();
```

то передаваемый в этот bridge-метод параметр будет проверен на этапе компиляции и не даст вам выстрелить в ногу.

[Рекомендую](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0c9Fd9FacU)

Comment: Прикольная ссылка, спасибо.